# System.Numerics when targeting net45

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, biginteger, project.json

From what I've understood, it should be possible to target net45 with the new xproj/project.json project settings in Visual Studio 2015.
So, I created a new project, under web templates in the file->new project menu, edited the project.json and Class1.cs as listed below.

project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-beta8",

  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime.Numerics": "4.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Class1.cs:

```
using System.Numerics;

namespace NumericTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            var biginteger = BigInteger.Parse("1234567890");
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> .NET Framework 4.5 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Numerics'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

If I update the target framework to "dotnet", it compiles just fine. But how do I use the System.Numerics (and more specifically, BigInteger class) when targeting net45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an assembly reference to `System.Numerics.dll` in your project.

Comment: Doooh! Thanx! 
When I did that VS added a frameworkAssemblies entry to my project.json. Thank you very much!